# db4o on Android 4.4.+: storing an object fails because cannot cast long to integer

Tags: android, db4o

While running db4o library (Both 8.1-SNAPSHOT and 8.0), opening the database works

`oc = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(dbConfig(), db4oDBFullPath(context));`
   `//context.getDir("data", 0) + "/" + "mDB.DB4O"; to get the full path`

However, once I start trying to store an object

> oc.store(object)

I get the error, `cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.lang.Integer`. This problem is caused probably by the new dalvik implementation for the new Android OS versions, but is there any patches or workarounds for this error available?

A guy was introducing a patch [here](http://community.versant.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/12297/Default.aspx) but it's inaccessible.

Full stacktrace of the error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>    at com.db4o.internal.DalvikVM$Dalvik3ObjectFactoryFactory.(DalvikVM.java:120)
>    at com.db4o.internal.DalvikVM.factory(DalvikVM.java:75)
>    at com.db4o.internal.DalvikVM.supportSkipConstructorCall(DalvikVM.java:55)
>    at com.db4o.internal.Platform4.callConstructor(Platform4.java:463)
>    at com.db4o.reflect.core.ConstructorSupport.createConstructor(ConstructorSupport.java:21)
>    at com.db4o.reflect.jdk.JdkClass.constructorSpec(JdkClass.java:176)
>    at com.db4o.reflect.jdk.JdkClass.ensureCanBeInstantiated(JdkClass.java:182)
>    at com.db4o.reflect.generic.GenericClass.ensureCanBeInstantiated(GenericClass.java:282)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.createConstructor(ClassMetadata.java:684)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.initializeConstructor(ClassMetadata.java:648)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.initializeAspects(ClassMetadata.java:266)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.checkChanges(ClassMetadata.java:494)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadataRepository.readClassMetadata(ClassMetadataRepository.java:465)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadataRepository.classMetadataForId(ClassMetadataRepository.java:259)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.classMetadataForID(ObjectContainerBase.java:1069)
>    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.ObjectHeader.(ObjectHeader.java:39)
>    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.ObjectHeader.(ObjectHeader.java:23)
>    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.readObjectHeader(UnmarshallingContext.java:124)
>    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.read(UnmarshallingContext.java:47)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:306)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:292)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.getByID2(ObjectContainerBase.java:886)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.getByID(ObjectContainerBase.java:857)
>    at com.db4o.internal.fileheader.FileHeaderVariablePart.readIdentity(FileHeaderVariablePart.java:44)
>    at com.db4o.internal.fileheader.NewFileHeaderBase.readIdentity(NewFileHeaderBase.java:92)
>    at com.db4o.internal.LocalObjectContainer.readThis(LocalObjectContainer.java:497)
>    at com.db4o.internal.IoAdaptedObjectContainer.openImpl(IoAdaptedObjectContainer.java:71)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$1.run(ObjectContainerBase.java:140)
>    at com.db4o.foundation.DynamicVariable.with(DynamicVariable.java:54)
>    at com.db4o.foundation.Environments.runWith(Environments.java:28)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.withEnvironment(ObjectContainerBase.java:161)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.open(ObjectContainerBase.java:131)
>    at com.db4o.internal.IoAdaptedObjectContainer.(IoAdaptedObjectContainer.java:35)
>    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerFactory.openObjectContainer(ObjectContainerFactory.java:18)
>    at com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.java:64)

Update:

So, after tracing the error, it turns out that there is a terrible cast from Long to Integer inside `com.db4o.internal.DalvikVM` in version 8.0

> int _methodId;
>     _methodId = (Integer) constructorIdMethod.invoke(null,
>   Object.class);

I tried to fix this by declaring the variable as long. I recompiled and ran again on Android, I got another error which is 
`UnsupportedOperationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: newInstance [class java.lang.Class, int]`

Caused by this:

```
        try {
            _method = ObjectStreamClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", Class.class, Integer.TYPE); 
            _method.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
        } 
    }
```

Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's Dalvik? I've not heard of significant changes to it. Maybe you are referring to ART?

Comment: @Machinarius, have a look at the stacktrace? It's dalvik for sure.

Comment: I wouldn't take that as a surefire proof the phone is running on Dalvik. Check the dev settings.

Comment: I checked the phone and it shows it's Dalvik.

Comment: Hmm no idea then, sorry

Comment: @Machinarius , I found the bug, it's not in Dalvik. It's internal error in db4o. I'm posting an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a patch in the code of db4o 8.1

Here you go, the new JAR file and code changes are available in [this GITHUB repository](https://github.com/mohataher/db4o-android).  There is also a demo for testing the library on the repo.

I changed few lines in `com.db4o.internal.Platform4`. Basically I changed the order of JDKs to look up.

```
private static void createJdk() {


    Class<?>[] jdkFactories = {

            JDK_5.Factory.class,//1 switched both positions.
            DalvikVM.Factory.class,//2
            JDK_1_4.Factory.class,
            JDK_1_3.Factory.class,
            JDK_1_2.Factory.class,
            JDKReflect.Factory.class,
    };
    //-----
```

Comment: Glad you found the problem

Comment: Just tested in on Nexus 4 running Kitkat 4.4.2 and Samsung Galaxy S4 running Kitkat 4.4.4. Looks like its fixed. Thanks!

Comment: how we use db4o on android studio by adding what in gradle please ?